# setDrawSliceText(boolean) is deprecated

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there any way to solve `setDrawSliceText` is deprecated. I did not find any solution regarding this.

How to get `pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is deprecated, however in its javadoc it states:

```
/**
 * Set this to true to draw the entry labels into the pie slices (Provided by the getLabel() method of the PieEntry class).
 * Deprecated -> use setDrawEntryLabels(...) instead.
 *
 * @param enabled
 */
```

so use `setDrawEntryLabels` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here with Example :

```
    ArrayList<PieEntry> yvalues = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
    yvalues.add(new PieEntry(8f, "", 0));
    yvalues.add(new PieEntry(15f, "", 1));
    yvalues.add(new PieEntry(12f, "", 2));

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "");
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
```